# Filling gaps between borders/contours in images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, smoothing, flood-fill

I have two images that I will like to combine together and fill/remove the gaps between the borders after combining. The image on the left is the edge while the image on the right is the mask. (Ignore the little patch on the right picture but it will be nice to be able to remove it too)

[image: Border]
[image: Predicted Mask]

The expected result after combination is

[image: expected result]

but this is the current result achieved so far

[image: current result]

I have tried different strategies from scikit-image apis, which includes:

`ndi.binary_opening`, `ndi.binary_closing`, `morphology.{erosion, dilation, opening, closing}` but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Is it always on the one side? You could `cv2.floodFill()` the first mask from the left.

Comment: How does the right *mask* image affect the final result you want? It seems that you only want to fill in left of the left *edge* image, regardless of the contests of the *mask* image.

Comment: @HeinWessels, no the filling doesn't necessarily start from the left in all images. Sometimes the edges are horizontal, see other [examples](https://pasteboard.co/HB67xUh.jpg) (combined edges and mask on left, target on the right). So the direction of filling will be based on where majority of black pixels lie.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, I tried  cv2.floodFill but it fills the whole pixels leaving out only the [edges](https://pasteboard.co/HB6bw0I.png).

Comment: Is it assured that the edge in the *"edge image"* is contiguous (no gaps/breaks) and that it always touches/joins the outer edge of the picture in 2 distinct places?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be a basis for a strategy...

**Step 1:**

Start with the *"edge image"*. Randomly choose any white pixel. Flood fill with black using that pixel as the seed, or start point. This should fill one side of the edge. Remember the seed, and get centroid (and maybe area) of the new, filled in black area. Invert the filled-in image and get the centroid of the other part of the image.

You now know the centroids of both sides of the edge - as marked in red below:

[image]

**Step 2:**

Now move to the mask image. Maybe use dilation/erosion to fill in any smallish holes. Then run "labelling" on the image to get a list of the contiguous black blobs and their centroids and areas. Select the largest blob by area.

You should now have the centroid of the largest blob as marked in green below:

[image]

**Step 3:**

Now choose the nearer of the two red points to the green one and use the corresponding seed to do your fill.

---

It may better at Step 1 to repeatedly choose white seed points at random till you get a different centroid, rather than doing the inversion. That's because if you just invert and get the centroid, you don't know a good seed pixel. It's not certain that the centroid a good seed.

Comment: You mention that you can't be certain it's a good seed. Why do you say that? The centroid should be in the middle of the space-to-fill, which sounds like a good starting point to me? :) @Mark

Comment: @HeinWessels If you look at the third example (link in comments) you will see that it has lots of white "holes" and the centroid could fall in one of those and then when you do a flood fill, you will just fill the hole - I think. I may be wrong! I once used a centroid and a pesky capital `C` was input and of course the centroid of a big black `C` on a white background is white - not black!

Comment: That is true. But those holes exist *only* on the `mask` image, while the `edge` image only contains a line. If you `FloodFill` the `edge` image, then there is no holes to fall in, and the `FloodFill` should run smoothly. The example that was shown had the `edge` and `mask` image combined. @Mark

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to find the Center of Mass (CoM) of the *mask* function to determine which side to fill, and then use `floodFill` to the *edge* image from the CoM as seeding point.

You could try something like this:

```
# Calculate the Center of Mass
com = np.zeros(2)
sum = np.zeros(2)
for x in range(0, nu_of_rows):
    for y in range(0, num_of_cols):
        com += image[x][y] * np.array([x,y])
        sum += image[x][y]
com /= sum

# FloodFill a new image
h, w = mask_img.shape[:2]
new_image = mask_img.copy()
temp = np.zeros((h+2,w+2),np.uint8) # Needs to be 2 pixels wider/higher
cv2.FloodFill(new_image, temp, coi, 255, flags=cv2.FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY)
```

This will work if the line in your *edge* and *mask* images has values `255` and the backgrounds `0`. If this is not the case, first invert your two images with the following command:

```
inverted_img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
```

*Note:* I did not test this with your image, but rather with one of mine. So you might have to change something here and there. Here is my *rough* example working:

[image]